# Redux and Design Patterns

Tags: design-patterns, redux

I've been using Redux for several months and have a good feel for the unidirectional data flow. However, I'm not trained in OOP and Design Patterns. After listening to a [talk by Ralph E Johnson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImUcJctyUQ0&t=1377s) my first reaction was that the Observable Pattern is very similar to Redux/Flux flow, is that correct? Where does that analogy break down?

He talks about the Interfaces required to implement Observable Patterns - is this the sort of thinking that the authors of Redux/Flux architecture have in mind when designing these libraries/architectures?

Comment: Seems more like command or pub-sub to me. Actions (commands) are dispatched and are handled by reducers. Reducers don't "subscribe" to events--they get all of them and have to decide which ones to deal with.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, the Redux store itself is a simple observable/pub-sub implementation, with a single "change/updated" event emitter.  The use of actions and reducers has some similarities to CQRS and event sourcing as well.  See https://redux.js.org/introduction/motivation and https://redux.js.org/introduction/prior-art .

Answer (score 6):

In Redux the State Tree uses the Singleton pattern and the connect method uses the Observer pattern.

Taken from [An Obsession with Design Patterns: Redux](https://jobs.zalando.com/tech/blog/design-patterns-redux/?gh_src=4n3gxh1) by Andra Joy Lally.

Answer (score 4):

Redux is an implementation of the Flux pattern. Facebook came up with the Flux pattern because the MVC wasn't working very well* for them. :)  see link

**Before:** The MVC problem:

[image]

**After:** The Flux solution that introduces a uni-directional data flow:

[image]

For an in-depth technical overview, please check: https://facebookarchive.github.io/flux/docs/in-depth-overview

A nice overview is also discussed in this 22' YouTube video [Redux Origins: The History Behind the Popular Library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfpvI6DQAWM).

- *"It just didn't scale."*

Answer (score 0):

As for me, Redux is reactive implementation of MVC pattern. Because here we have Model (Store) with State, listen state changes with Observer pattern, use Controller to call methods of model (send Actions). But process of changing state is little bit different - by using Reducers. But approach is the same: Send command -> Change state -> Listen state changes.

There is a good explanation of MVC pattern in the book 'Patterns-Oriented Software Architecture'.
Here is a [scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G09Dx.png) from book how MVC works.

Comment: As [Konstantinos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8900387/konstantinos) pointed out Facebook created Flux pattern because MVC wasn't working for them. Then Redux was created and it was based on combination of [Flux](http://facebook.github.io/flux), [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), and [Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html). So pattern used in Redux is quite different. One example could be - MVC can have many Modals, while Redux has a single store which is single source of truth.